# closing ngDialog in controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

i have two function , one for opening dialog and one for posting data to  server and then close the dialog , the problem is i cant close dialog , here us the code

```
 vm.openCreateDialog = function () {

                 var Dialog = ngDialog.open({
                    template: 'user/create',
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
                })
            }
vm.createUser = function () {
           DataService.createUser(vm.user).then(function (response) {
                $log.log('promise returned successfully')
                Dialog.close();

            }).catch(function (e) {
                $log.log('catch registration error')

            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngDialog.open() return an object with id , the id is id of dialog box , I use it to close the dialog box , here is working code if anybody came to it

```
 vm.openCreateDialog = function () {

                 vm.Dialog = ngDialog.open({
                    template: 'user/create',
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',

                 })
                 vm.dialogId = vm.Dialog.id;
            }
```

and from another function I just used the id to close dialog

```
  ngDialog.close(vm.dialogId)
```

Answer (score 3):

ngDialog.close() will work.

From the document:

> .close(id, value) Method accepts dialog's id as string argument to
>   close specific dialog window, if id is not specified it will close all
>   currently active modals (same behavior as .closeAll()). Takes an
>   optional value to resolve the dialog promise with (or all dialog
>   promises).

Answer (score 0):

In the `openCreateDialog` you assign value to the `Dialog` variable, but it won't be accessible from anywhere else because it's local to `openCreateDialog`'s scope. More about how `var` statement works can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

To fix the issue, `Dialog` has to be visible from inside of other function. There are various ways to do this, but I would simply put it on the `vm` and access it from there:

```
 vm.Dialog = ngDialog.open({
 // ...
 vm.Dialog.close();
```

[JSFiddle working example](http://jsbin.com/nivawodeya/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: I Did same as your code , but I get the error .Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Comment: Maybe the version differs from what's in the documentation? A fiddle with reproduced issue would help to understand exactly why this happens.